# Mouse does not respond

Tags: 11.10, mouse

I've installed ubuntu 11.10 on a desktop computer, but it does not despond to any kind of mouse.

The mouse seems to be on, but the system doesn't respond not to the mouse movement nor to mouse clicks.

What can I do?

edit:
All USBs are not working, not mice and not DOKs

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in ubuntu 11.10 ,what you need to do is install a software synpatiks from software center...it helped me..try it.if mouse is not working then install via command line. press CTRL+ALT+T and then

```
sudo apt-get install synaptiks
```

try it

Comment: Sorry, just checked and apparently my external hard drive fried all USB exits .___.

Comment: No problem, install the drivers manually then

Comment: My point is there's no problem with drivers, I need to replace my mother board